# Automated setup for multi-server RethinkDB cluster via an ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, terraform, amazon-ecs

I'm attempting to set up a RethinkDB cluster with 3 servers total spread evenly across 3 private subnets, each in different AZ's in a single region.

Ideally, I'd like to deploy the DB software via ECS and provision the EC2 instances with auto scaling, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to instruct the RethinkDB instances to join a RethinkDB cluster.

To create/join a cluster in RethinkDB, when you start up a new instance of RethinkDB, you specify `host:port` combination of one of the other machines in the cluster. This is where I'm running into problems. The Auto Scaling service is creating new primary ENI's for my EC2 instances and using a random IP in my subnet's range, so I can't know the IP of the EC2 instance ahead of time. On top of that, I'm using `awsvpc` task networking, so ECS is creating new secondary ENI's dedicated to each docker container and attaching them to the instances when it deploys them and those are also getting new IP's, which I don't know ahead of time.

So far I've worked out one possible solution, which is to not use an autoscaling group, but instead to manually deploy 3 EC2 instances across the private subnets, which would let me assign my own, predetermined, private IP. As I understand it, this still doesn't help me if I'm using `awsvpc` task networking though because each container running on my instances will get its own dedicated secondary ENI and I wont know the IP of that secondary ENI ahead of time. I think I can switch my task networking to `bridge` mode, to get around this. That way I can use the predetermined IP of the EC2 instances (the primary ENI) in the RethinkDB `join` command.

So In conclusion, the only way to achieve this, that I can figure out, is to not use Auto Scaling, or `awsvpc` task networking, both of which would otherwise be very desirable features. Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

Comment: Is the issue not more that the first instance needs to start separately and then the others need to join to it? I've seen this with Consul which then got around things by using discovery of other peers via some mechanism (such as AWS instance tags) but before then you needed to start one Consul instance and then the others would need to join to it. In this case you need to define the order of these and essentially create a "special" RethinkDB instance that represents the first node to be deployed but that may have issues around availability of that instance.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR this sounds like it's on the right track yeah! Could you elaborate a little more in an answer? Perhaps show me a sample terraform snippet or something?

Comment: I've explained the general principle in more detail including fleshing out a bit with what services you'd use to do this but not supported by any code (yet). If I get a chance I'll try to mock up a PoC that properly demonstrates things but that might not be for a while. Feel free to edit my answer with actual code if you get something working.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is more of an issue around the fact you need to start a single RethinkDB instance one time to bootstrap the cluster and then handle discovery of the existing cluster members when joining new members to the cluster.

I would have thought RethinkDB would have published a good pattern in their docs for this because it's going to be pretty common when setting up clusters but I couldn't see anything useful in their docs. If someone does know of an official recommendation then you should definitely use this rather than what I'm about to propose especially as I have no experience with running RethinkDB.

This is more just spit-balling here and will be completely untested (at least for now) but the principle is going to be you need to start a single, one off instance of RethinkDB to bootstrap the cluster, then have more cluster members join and then ditch the special case bootstrap member that didn't attempt to join a cluster and leave the remaining cluster members to work.

The bootstrap instance is easy enough to consider. You just need a RethinkDB container image and an ECS task that just runs it in stand-alone mode with the ECS service only running one instance of the task. To enable the second set of cluster members to easily discover cluster members including this bootstrapping instance it's probably easiest to use a service discovery mechanism such as [the one offered by ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html) which uses Route53 records under the covers. The ECS service should register the service in the `RethinkDB` namespace.

Then you should create another ECS service that's basically the same as the first but in an entrypoint script should list the services in the `RethinkDB` namespace and then resolve them, discarding the container's own IP address and then uses the discovered host to join to with `--join` when starting RethinkDB in the container.

I'd then set the non bootstrap ECS service to just 1 task at first to allow it to discover the bootstrap version and then you should be able to keep adding tasks to the service one at a time until you're happy with the size of the non bootstrapped cluster leaving you with n + 1 instances in the cluster including the original bootstrap instance.

After that I'd remove the bootstrap ECS service entirely.

If an ECS task dies in the non bootstrap ECS service dies for whatever reason it should be able to auto rejoin without any issue as it will just find a running RethinkDB task and start that.

You could probably expand the checks for which cluster member to join to by checking that the RethinkDB port is open and running before using that as a member to join so it will handle multiple tasks being started at the same time (with my original suggestion it could potentially find another task that is looking to join the cluster and try to join to that first, with them all potentially deadlocking if they all failed to randomly pick the existing cluster members by chance).

As mentioned, this answer comes with a big caveat that I haven't got any experience running RethinkDB and I've only played with the service discovery mechanism that was recently released for ECS so might be missing something here but the general principles should hold fine.